# Chrome does not open Symfoy generated PDF

Tags: symfony, google-chrome, pdf

While testing my Symfony 2.8 based web app I came across the problem, that Chrome (58.0.3029.96) does not open generated PDF files:

- A form POSTs some data to a Symfony Controller
- The Controllers generates the PDF Content and returns it as response
- All tested browsers but Chrome correctly display the generated PDF
- Chrome displays an PDF View (no pages, etc. just the controls for zooming, etc. while viewing a PDF file)

The Source:

```
// Rendered HTML Form
<form name="form" method="post" action="/report/generate" target="_blank">
    ...    
</form>

// Symfony Controller
public function generateAction(Request $request) { 
    ...

    $report_pdf = $this->pdfGenerator->generatePDF(...);

    $header = array(
        'Content-Type' => 'application/pdf',
        'Content-Disposition' => 'inline; filename="Report.pdf"',
    );

    return new Response($report_pdf, 200, $header);
}
```

Chrome does not show any error. Only when using the developer tools the following error can be found in the console

> Error: Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/pdf

I found several threads about this error but all dealing with other circumstances. None of the proposed solutions worked:

- Using `Content-Disposition: inline` without `filename` does not make any difference
- Using `Content-Disposition: attachment: filename="Report.pdf"` downloads the file instead of showing it. Opening the downloaded file in Chrome is no problem, thus the PDF seems to be OK
- Adding `Content-Length` header does not make any difference
- Removing `target="_blank"` from the form-tag does not make any difference (beside no new tab is created, of course)

**Any other ideas how to solve this?**

Comment: You are missing a closing-quote in `'Content-Disposition' => 'inline; filename="Report.pdf',` - doubt that's the issue though since you tried different things... just wanted to mention this.

Comment: Thank for the hint, but this was just a copy error and (as you assumed) not the cause of the problem.